# Creating chat using listview (Android)

Tags: android, xml, listview

I'm trying to add a simple chat program inside my application which would display messages entered by the user to the right side and the messages coming from the other user(server) to the left side. I understand that I would need to create my own customAdapter but after watching several tutorials I still can't seem to grasp the understanding on how to create my own adapter that would fulfill my requirements. I know this might sound silly and inexperienced but any help on how to go about this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, and try to search more there are so many sample examples too :

```
public class ChatArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

private EmojiconTextView chatText;
private List chatMessageList = new ArrayList();
private LinearLayout singleMessageContainer,backgroundLayout;

public void add(ChatMessage object) {
    chatMessageList.add(object);
    super.add(object);
}

public ChatArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId);
}

public int getCount() {
    return this.chatMessageList.size();
}

public ChatMessage getItem(int index) {
    return (ChatMessage) this.chatMessageList.get(index);
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, parent, false);
    }
    singleMessageContainer = (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.singleMessageContainer);
    backgroundLayout = (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.backgroundLayout);

    ChatMessage chatMessageObj = getItem(position);
    chatText = (EmojiconTextView) row.findViewById(R.id.singleMessage);
    chatText.setText(chatMessageObj.message);

    backgroundLayout.setBackgroundResource(chatMessageObj.left ? R.drawable.balloon_incoming_focused : R.drawable.balloon_outgoing_focused);

    singleMessageContainer.setGravity(chatMessageObj.left ? Gravity.LEFT : Gravity.RIGHT);


    return row;
}


}
```

In Main Activity :

```
    ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv);
    chatArrayAdapter = new ChatArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(),   R.layout.activity_main);
    listView.setAdapter(chatArrayAdapter);
```

And this is ChatMessag

```
    public class ChatMessage {
    public boolean left;
    public String message;

    public ChatMessage(boolean left, String message) {
        super();
        this.left = left;
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```